# nebulagraph-storaged: Exited– 9780 Address already in use

Tags: nebula-graph

The `nebula-storage` service failed to start, the storage logs show that the port is occupied, but I checked that port `9780` is not occupied either. Also the configuration files are original and unmodified.

Comment: You could go and check processes that’s running with nebula key word like ps -ef | grep nebula, there could be some old ones out there. Kill them could release the occupied ports

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the health of the framework, please ask one. You can see [ask] for guidance. Note: ['Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several reasons why the nebula-storage service is failing to start:

1. Another process is already using port 9780. You can use the `lsof -i tcp:9780` command to check which process is using the port.
2. There is a problem with the nebula-storage service itself. You can try restarting the service.